# Core Data Predicate Filter By Today's Date

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, nspredicate

How can I filter Core Data Managed Objects by their `Date` attribute in Swift?

The goal is to filter fetched objects by today's date.

Comment: Pre-Swift 3 question and answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688952/how-fetch-objects-with-nsdate-of-today-using-nspredicate.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't simply use to compare your date to today's date:

```
let today = Date()
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(ModelType.date), today)
```

It will show you nothing since it's unlikely that your date is the EXACT comparison date (it includes seconds & milliseconds too)

The solution is this:

```
// Get the current calendar with local time zone
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

// Get today's beginning & end
let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) // eg. 2016-10-10 00:00:00
let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)
// Note: Times are printed in UTC. Depending on where you live it won't print 00:00:00 but it will work with UTC times which can be converted to local time

// Set predicate as date being today's date
let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ >= %K", dateFrom as NSDate, #keyPath(ModelType.date))
let toPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K < %@", #keyPath(ModelType.date), dateTo as NSDate)
let datePredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [fromPredicate, toPredicate])
fetchRequest.predicate = datePredicate
```

It's by far the easiest & shortest way of showing only objects which have today's date.

Comment: Don't use 86400 seconds as the duration of a day (think of daylight saving time transitions). Use the proper calendar methods. Passing both dates as an array is wrong, try it and print the predicate !

Comment: Your first example `NSPredicate(format: "date == Date()")` would actually *crash*.

Comment: Yes, the 86400 seconds is a rudimentary implementation. I'll update the answer with a better solution. And thanks for the array reminder. You can pass an argument array. With the updated function the code works just fine.

Comment: where is the fetchRequest?

Comment: what if we want to add 24 hours? Not for day.

Comment: @Manish I think you replace "calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)" with Țcalendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 24, to: dateFrom)". Just an idea. Haven't touched this code in years and I haven't checked if it's .hour and not .hours. Just go check it in Xcode. Also, I think it's the same thing since 1 day = 24 hours.

Comment: How can I embed this code inside @FetchRequest( entity: CDReminder.entity(),
                   sortDescriptors:[],
                   predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", Date() as CVarArg)
    )var reminder: FetchedResults<CDReminder>

Comment: This line `let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ >= %K", dateFrom as NSDate, #keyPath(ModelType.date))` should be replaced with `let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ <= %K", dateFrom as NSDate, #keyPath(ModelType.date))` (note the less than or equal instead of greater than or equal)

Answer (score 10):

In swift4, Lawrence413's can be simplify a bit:

```
//Get today's beginning & end
let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) // eg. 2016-10-10 00:00:00
let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)
```

---

It get rid of the `component` part, makes the code have better readability.

Comment: I think @lawrence413 was looking for a solution for swift3.

Answer (score 6):

Might be helpful to add to Lawrence413's answer that to filter a list of records with an attribute holding today's date, you could use:

```
let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "datetime >= %@", dateFrom as NSDate)
let toPredicate   = NSPredicate(format: "datetime < %@",  dateToUnwrapped as NSDate)
```

...Where "datetime is the name of the attribute"