# How to persist tableview rows?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am creating an ios app that will show me a user specific set of tasks everyday that i click to delete to show its done. I save the tasks in core data, and just delete the tableview row on click. I dont delete the data in coredata as its userdefined and need to reload it everyday. I use a newDay() function to decide to load data from coredata if the app is opened on a new day. What should i do to remember which all tasks have been done for the day? Do i need to create another enitity to remember which all tasks are completed or is there an simpler way?

```
var tasks: [NSManagedObject] = []
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var calender = Calendar.current

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "DailyTasker"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let checkDate = newDay()
    if checkDate{

    //1
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Task")

    //3
    do {
        tasks = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "LastRun")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    }
}

func newDay() -> Bool{
    if let lastRun = defaults.object(forKey: "LastRun") as? Date{
        if !calender.isDateInToday(lastRun){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return true
    }

}


@IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Task",
                                  message: "Add a new task",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
                                   style: .default) {
                                    [unowned self] action in

                                    guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
                                        let nameToSave = textField.text else {
                                            return
                                    }

                                    self.save(name: nameToSave)
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                     style: .default)

    alert.addTextField()

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alert, animated: true)
}

func save(name: String) {

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    // 1
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // 2
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Task",
                                   in: managedContext)!

    let task = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                               insertInto: managedContext)

    // 3
    task.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

    // 4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        tasks.append(task)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return tasks.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskerCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = task.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String

    return cell
}       

 // Override to support editing the table view.
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 if editingStyle == .delete {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
 tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
 } else if editingStyle == .insert {

 }
 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a date attribute to your task and name it `lastDone`for instance. Then you set that to current date time when a task is done and also use a predicate when fetching task instances so you only get those not done today.

```
 task.lastDone = Date()
```

I am not sure how you define "today" but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312105/core-data-predicate-filter-by-todays-date) should help you create a predicate that properly filters your task although you might also want to include tasks where `lastDone` is null.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Why you can't delete the data. Is it due to specifications.
If not then, when you save your task in coredata simply assign it with a unique Identifer(id) and then you can create your own data stack Method to delete the specific task.

You can create a data Model Class or struct for the task example

```
class TaskData {
  var id: Int!
  var task: String!

  init(id: Int, task: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.task = task
  }
}
```

Save task as this dataClass into coreData.

When you delete the row at that time captue the Task Id and delete it from coreDataStack.

A good way will be to create a TaskManager Singelton class to handle all the core data Methods.

Comment: I dont want to delete the task in coreData as i want to reload my tableview everyday with all the tasks from coreData. This is a task repetition app.