# The begining of a day (not today)

Tags: swift, date

I try to get the beginning and end of a day. (It could be any day not necessarily today)

What I have tried:

```
let input = "12/10/2018" // it could be any day
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let date = formatter.date(from: input)
print(date!) // it prints: 2018-12-09 23:00:00 +0000
```

- Why in this example does it print 23, by default?
- How can I get the beginning of a day? (day and time UTC)
- How to get the end of that day? (day and time UTC)

(In many places talk about getting the beginning of Day(). For instance: [Core Data Predicate Filter By Today's Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312105/core-data-predicate-filter-by-todays-date)

But what I am asking is about any day.)

Comment: Set the time zone for the formatter to use, `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson. Ok, it works to get the beginning of the day UTC. Do you know how can I get the end of the day?

Comment: In other words, the beginning of next day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Calendar` to perform date math:

```
let input = "12/10/2018" // it could be any day
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

let date = formatter.date(from: input)!
print(date) // it prints: 2018-12-09 23:00:00 +0000

let calendar = Calendar.current
let nextDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
print(nextDay)
```

Comment: Why wrappingComponents ?

Comment: True, that's not what you'd want in this case - I misread the docs.

Answer (score 2):

```
let input = "12/10/2018"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

let startOfDate = formatter.date(from: input)
let dateIntervalDuration = formatter.calendar.dateInterval(of: .day,  for: startOfDate!)?.duration
let endOfDate = startOfDate?.addingTimeInterval(dateIntervalDuration! - 1)

print(startOfDate!)
print(endOfDate!)
```

Comment: *86400 date math* is strongly discouraged. Consider that there are days with 23 and 25 hours (daylight saving time changes).

Answer (score 0):

Date formatters take in account your time zone. The print() function doesn't. So the result of "let date = ... " is the start of the day in your local time zone. What print () displays is the date and time in UTC. You're one hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, how can I get the beginning and end date and time UTC of let input?

Answer (score 0):

What most people do not know (at least I assume this, because I didn't know it until a few weeks ago when I had to grapple with this very problem) is that a calendar can have a time zone. So if you have a date-time and you configure a `.gregorian` calendar with a particular time zone, e.g. UTC, now you can just call `startOfDay(for:)` and you'll get the right answer.

For example:

```
let tz = TimeZone.current
var greg = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
greg.timeZone = tz // or whatever
let d = Date() // or whatever
let start = greg.startOfDay(for: d)
print(start) // 2020-03-15 07:00:00 +0000
```

And that is correct: when it was 7 AM on March 15 2020 UTC, that was the start of day (midnight) where I was at the moment I ran this code.

Comment: So, how would you apply that here?

Comment: I wouldn't. _You_ would apply it here. I already applied it where I needed it. :)

Comment: @Nrc Since input is a string with a date only this will be handled by the formatter in your case

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The question asked for the start of the day, not some words to show the user. I assume that what is wanted is the real honest-to-goodness start of the day. That is what my answer produces.

Comment: My comment was meant for OP