# swift coredata query not working for today's date

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a class named Places managed by CoreData. This object has a Date object as a timestamp.

I have this query to probe for only today's places. The issue is that I have only 2 places logged in today, however it's yielding me 21 records, which I do not expect

```
func updatePlaceMarksForADateFromDatabase(date: Date) {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
    let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
    let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)
    
    // Set predicate as date being compliant with date
    let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ >= %@", date as NSDate, dateFrom as NSDate)
    let toPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ < %@", date as NSDate, dateTo! as NSDate)
    let datePredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [fromPredicate, toPredicate])

    // CoreData API's to list only today places
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Places> = Places.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = datePredicate
    if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?
        .persistentContainer.viewContext {
      let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Places.timestamp), ascending: false)
      fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
      if let placesCoreData = try?
          context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
        // Store it to the cache
        print(placesCoreData.count)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your predicate... It should be something like `%K >= %@, #keyPath(Places.nameOfTheVariableHoldingTheDate), dateFrom`, and `%K < %@, #keyPath(Places.nameOfTheVariableHoldingTheDate), dateTo`

Comment: @larme it looks like it comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312106/9223839) which is kind of weird since this nonsense predicate has 40 upvotes, maybe I’m missing something…

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Good catch. If I understood, that the property was named `date`, and there have been a very wrong edit on it... The last one: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40312106/revisions It's good on the first sample code with KeyPath, but absolutely wrong on the second piece of code...

Comment: @Larme I’ve edited that answer now, hopefully it’s correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate are wrong.

```
let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ >= %@", date as NSDate, dateFrom as NSDate)
let toPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ < %@", date as NSDate, dateTo! as NSDate)
let datePredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [fromPredicate, toPredicate])
```

You aren't testing it against the properties of `Places`. Currently, it's equivalent to `NSPredicate(value: true)`, because `date` is greater or equal to `dateFrom` and less that `dateTo`. It should always be true (according to how values are created). That's why you are getting all the places when fetching.

It should be:

```
let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Places.dateVariableName), dateFrom]
let toPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K < %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Places.dateVariableName), dateTo]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Yes I need to include the places. Thanks everyone for helping