# Initializing new entity to provide template for fetched result

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am creating an app that lets users track the calories they ate each day.  It creates a new entity called "Day" that has a date attribute "date" and a float attribute "calories".

In a second view controller, the user selects a date with a datePicker which is then set to the date value "selectedDate".  Now what I want is to fetch the entity that matches the selectedDate and set a specific UILabel to the the calories float result from that date.

The problem now is that I can't seem to properly create the array "result" to be filled with the entity that has the selectedDate.  After running the printDay function, it always prints 0 which means the fetch is not adding any entity to the result array, but I'm not sure why.

```
 class secondViewController {
 var result: [Day] = []

 func loadItems() {
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Day> = Day.fetchRequest()
    
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date == %@", selectedDate as CVarArg)

    do {
    result = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error saving content \(error)")
    }
 }

 func printDay () {
 print("\(result.count)")
 }
```

Comment: You're getting the error about initializers because you don't have an initial value specified for `result`. You could make it an optional `Day?` and the error would go away, for example. In terms of the second error, your predicate returns an array of `Day` (ie `[Day]`) -- every instance that matches the predicate. So, you could, for example, take only the first returned item.

Comment: To add to what @jnpdx has said, you can also mark the variable `result` for auto unwrapping, to do that change the type of `result` to `Day!`. This way none of your existing code requires change to handle unwrapping. Just make sure the first time you are reading `result` there is already some value present or your app will crash.

Comment: No, do not use implicit unwrapping (!) unless you have very good reason to and this is not the case. To clarify one thing about a fetch. `context.fetch(...)` will always return an array even if it finds only one object, it will then return an array containing only that object.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried changing it to an array but it seems the fetch isn't adding my intended entity into the array, any suggestions?  (I updated the code in original question)

Comment: Most likely you don’t get an exact match on the date if you use the Date type since it contains time as well. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312105/core-data-predicate-filter-by-todays-date