# Filtering Core Data with predicate to only show entries for today (filter stops working)

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, filtering, predicate

Expected behavior:

- The user enters at least one entry per day.
- The user sees a button for "Please make an entry"
- Unless they already have then the button says "Saved" and if they tap it it goes to HistoryView. (The button switch to Navigation visually indicates something happened).

My thinking was to apply a predicate on the date to filter by start of day and use and if statement to swap what they see.

When I apply the code below, it works fine in the simulator and in the app, but *after a few days* the predicate stops working. I open the app at the beginning of the day and it says "Saved". I can't figure out what is breaking after about 2-3 nights. Not  sure if this is the best solution to achieve the result.

Also, if I kill the app and reload, everything is fine again.

I tried a version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312105/core-data-predicate-filter-by-todays-date) answer, but I'm still new to coding and maybe am not doing something right because it didn't work at all (showed all results in core data).

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct HomeScreenView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var backgroundSet: Background
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Entry.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.date, ascending: true)], predicate: nil, animation: .default)

private var entries: FetchedResults<Entry>

        init(){
            var calendar = Calendar.current
            calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
            let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) // eg. 2016-10-10 00:00:00
            let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format : "date <= %@ AND  date >= %@", dateTo! as CVarArg, dateFrom as CVarArg)
            self._entries = FetchRequest(
                entity: Entry.entity(),
                sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.date, ascending: false)],
                predicate: predicate)
        }

 @State var presentSheet = false
    @State private var today : Date = Date()

 var body: some View {

        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {

if entries.count == 0 {
                        Button("Please make an entry?") {
                            presentSheet = true
                            //refresh.toggle()
                        }
                        .frame(minWidth: 250, minHeight: 50, alignment: .center).padding()
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .padding()
                    } else {
                        NavigationLink(destination: HistoryView()) {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Saved for today.")
                                Text("Click here to view history.")
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(minWidth: 250, minHeight: 50, alignment: .center).padding()
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                        .padding()
                    }

            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
                AddEntryView()
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])   
            }
```

Here's a copy of persistence:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newEntry = Entry(context: viewContext)
            newEntry.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Express_Gratitude")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {              
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

Here's what in @main

```
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
}
}
```

From the link above, I tried a version of this and it didn't work. I could be implementing this completely wrong...open to the education and suggestions to achieve the result.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct HomeScreenView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var backgroundSet: Background
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Entry.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.date, ascending: true)], predicate: nil, animation: .default)
    
    private var entries: FetchedResults<Entry>
    
    init(){
        // Get the current calendar with local time zone
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        // Get today's beginning & end
        let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) // eg. 2016-10-10 00:00:00
        let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: dateFrom)
        // Note: Times are printed in UTC. Depending on where you live it won't print 00:00:00 but it will work with UTC times which can be converted to local time
        // Set predicate as date being today's date
        let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ >= %K", dateFrom as NSDate, #keyPath(Entry.date))
        let toPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K < %@", #keyPath(Entry.date), dateTo! as NSDate)
        let datePredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [fromPredicate, toPredicate])
        self._entries = FetchRequest(
            entity: Entry.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entry.date, ascending: false)],
            predicate: datePredicate)
    }

    @State var presentSheet = false
    @State private var today : Date = Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the predicate when the day changes, e.g.

```
var timerForNextMidnight: Timer {
    ....
}

.onReceive(timerForNextMidnight) { timer in
    entries.predicate = ...
}
```

Note you also need to use this calendar, so the timer is recreated if the user changes their calendar in Settings while the app is running.

```
@Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
```